# Where clause to get last record created

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ would like to use a where clause to get last record created in table.

Not sure of exact syntax:

```
POSUnitRecord lastDownloadedPOS = lastDownloadedPOS .Where...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with

```
lastDownloadedPOS.OrderByDescending(x => x.?????).FirstOrDefault();
```

Where `????` would be the name of the property holding the date you're after

Answer (score 0):

Use following query:

```
  POSUnitRecord lastDownloadedPOS = lastDownloadedPOS .Where(p=>p.columnName==value).OrderByDescending(p=>p.columnName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

The last record on the database whould probably have the newest timestamp.

Try to use the max function of linq instead of the where to retrieve one record containing the timestamp, another query could then be done to retrieve the last record.

```
DateTime lastRecord = lastDownloadedPos.Max(a=>a.Timestamp);
lastDownloadedPos.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.Timestamp == lastRecord);
```

Comment: `Max` would return the maximum timestamp, not the record in question. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549271(v=vs.110).aspx for documentation on this method.

Comment: Ofcourse, thanx Chris, I totally forgot. There is a nuget library called morelinq which has great extensions. One of them is called MaxBy which will return the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of your collection, you can do this:

```
POSUnitRecord lastDownloadedPOS = lastDownloadedPOSCollection.Last();
```